# db.savechanges saves record twice

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, savechanges

I have the following foreach statment

```
foreach (var e in empList)
        {
            db.EmployeeForecasts.Add(e);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The empList contains only 1 record, but db.SaveChanges() saves the record twice in the database?

Can someone please explain why this is happening and what I can do about it?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post some details about the types of empList and the whole function? Sure it gets called only once?

Comment: You should use SQL Server Profiler and VS debugger to get to know on what step the record gets duplicated.

Comment: Are there duplicate records in `empList`?

Comment: this is not the answer for your question but, you should save changes after closing the loop. and you can also use `AddRange(empList)`

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which can be compiled and tested by others, which shows that duplicates are added.

Comment: There is only one record in empList. The controller is an formcollection, it worked perfectly before and suddenly it saves the record twice? Is it possible to check db.EmployeeForecast to see if the record is added twice?

Comment: I also tried to save it by alling a stored proedure. But the same result, it saves the record twice?

Comment: I tried it with AddRange, but the same result, record save twice.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your db holds already the entity. Instead of using the add, you should look at

```
foreach (var e in empList)
        {
            db.EmployeeForecasts.Attach(e);
    }
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This is interesting, did you instantiate the db context just before the foreach? Can you put it in a using so we are sure it only runs your little piece of cod ewith the Add.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was s stupid mistake. I use JQuery to submit the form, but I called the controller twice. So it's obvious it saved the record twice. Thank you for your help.